# Bash variable assignment using another variable as part

Tags: bash, scripting

I have the following excerpt from a bash script used to backup a database

```
#!/bin/bash
DB=database_name
DBUSER=username
FILENAME=$DB_$(date +%s).sql
```

I am trying to reuse the value of `DB` within the `FILENAME` variable assignment, but it won't let me use substitution this way. I just get the timestamp for the file name.

Is it possible to achieve what I want, and if so what is the syntax?

thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that `bash` does not know that you mean `$DB` instead of `$DB_` (which is a perfectly valid name for a variable).

The best option is to be explicit on the name of the variable using braces around its name:

```
FILENAME=${DB}_$(date %s).sql
```

This saves you the trouble of escaping other characters which are not to be interpreted as part of a variable name.

Comment: I ended up accepting this answer as I found it more complete. I also find the braces to be more readable. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Alternately, use braces to isolate your variable. I think it's a bit clearer than putting quotes in there.

```
FILENAME=${DB}_$(date +%s).sql
```

Comment: Also works within quotes: `FILENAME="${DB}_$(date +%s)"` if you want to embed stars or spaces or something.

Answer (score 2):

Enclose the underscore in double quotes (or single quotes for the stronger):

```
#!/bin/bash
DB=database_name
DBUSER=username
FILENAME=$DB"_"$(date +%s).sql
```

Comment: Legend. It won't let me accept this for 9 minutes, but you have made me a momentarily happy man. Cheers.